# Solo marcar un checkbox a la vez en un gridview

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Tengo un gridview que posee un checkbox, estoy intentando que el usuario solo pueda seleccionar una casilla a la vez, si hace clic en otra casilla pues que se desmarque la primera seleccionada. Estoy intentando hacerlo con javascript sin embargo no me funciona.

ASP

C#

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            string strScript = "uncheckOthers(" + ((CheckBox)e.Row.Cells[0].FindControl("SelectCheckBox")).ClientID + ");";
            ((CheckBox)e.Row.Cells[0].FindControl("SelectCheckBox")).Attributes.Add("onclick", strScript);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception Ex)
    {
        //report error
    }
}
```

javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function uncheckOthers(id) {
        var elm = document.getElementsByTagName('<%=SelectCheckBox.ClientID%>');
        for (var i = 0; i < elm.length; i++) {
            if (elm.item(i).type == "checkbox" && elm.item(i) != id)
                elm.item(i).checked = false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

NOTA: No uso radio button porque no es funcional ya que cambia el ID y lo necesito para otro metodo.

Comment: como es eso que cambia el id el radiobutton ?

Comment: Leandro me base en lo que tu dices en este en lace.https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/e5cc38bb-3f78-4146-b3ab-1014a3076d5c/radio-button-y-gridview?forum=netfxwebes

Comment: si es verdad, lo resuelve pero es algo rebuscado como lo consigue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al final lo solucione desde el codigo de asp.net. No requiere ninguna acción desde el servidor

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function CheckOne(obj) {
                var grid = obj.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
                var inputs = grid.getElementsByTagName("input");
                for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
                    if (inputs[i].type == "checkbox") {
                        if (obj.checked && inputs[i] != obj && inputs[i].checked) {
                            inputs[i].checked = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        </script>
        <asp:GridView ID="gridSeguimiento" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" CellPadding="4"
            Font-Bold="False" ForeColor="#333333" HorizontalAlign="Center" PageSize="5" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            OnSelectedIndexChanged="gridSeguimiento_SelectedIndexChanged" Caption="Despachos"
            Visible="False" Width="869px">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="SelectCheckBox" runat="server" onclick="CheckOne(this)" OnCheckedChanged="SelectCheckBox_OnCheckedChanged" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" SelectText="Detalle" ItemStyle-Width="30" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="SEC_DESPACHO" HeaderText="N° Despacho" ItemStyle-Width="80" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="DES_TIPO_ENVIO" HeaderText="Tipo Envio" ItemStyle-Width="80" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="NUM_TIPO_ENVIO" HeaderText="N° Conocimiento" ItemStyle-Width="80" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="NUM_FACTURA" HeaderText="N° Factura" ItemStyle-Width="80" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FEC_ESTIMADA_ARRIBO_PAIS" HeaderText="Fec Est País" ItemStyle-Width="80" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FEC_ESTIMADA_ARRIBO_BODEGA" HeaderText="Fec Est Bod" ItemStyle-Width="80" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FEC_ARRIBO_PAIS" HeaderText="Fec Arribo País" ItemStyle-Width="100" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FEC_ARRIBO_BODEGA" HeaderText="Fec Arribo Bodega" ItemStyle-Width="100" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FEC_DESPACHO_FABRICA" HeaderText="Fecha Desp Fab" ItemStyle-Width="100" />
            </Columns>
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
            <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
        </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias me fue de gran ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Deberias hacer la seleccion en base al parametro que asignaste en el `RowDataBound`

Aquise observan algunas ideas interesantes de como iterar

[Implement check all checkbox functionality in ASP.Net GridView control using JavaScript](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Implement-check-all-checkbox-functionality-in-ASPNet-GridView-control-using-JavaScript.aspx)

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

    function uncheckOthers(id) 
    {
        var elm = document.getElementById(id);

        var row = elm.parentNode.parentNode;

        var GridView = row.parentNode;

        var inputList = GridView.getElementsByTagName("input");

        for (var i=0;i<inputList.length;i++)
        {
            if(inputList[i].type == "checkbox" 
                && inputList[i].id != elm.id)
            {
                inputList[i].checked = false;
            }

        }
</script>
```

valida si como en el ejemplo puedes usar el `onclick` en el html en luagar de asignarlo en el `RowDataBound`

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" onclick="uncheckOthers(this)" />
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias Leandro me diste una gran guía, publicaré la respuesta correcta por si alguien más tiene este problema algún día